# Waiting for change in XML (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, post

so I've got ajax post method in javascript which on complete returns XML document. Problem is that when it returns XML document, one of the tags' value is *"processing"* and I need somehow to know when it is *"done"*. I only receive *"processing"* and never *"done"*, which I understand why is that (I've got full document, no need to wait for another one).

Is there a way to write a callback in "complete:" part of ajax method? I want to know exactly when it's done. Or should I use some active timing to check on server (rather not to).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quote: "when it returns XML document, one of the tags' value is "processing" and I need somehow to know when it is "done"."... What is changing your XML contents?

Comment: I send something to server and this server process sent data, if I want to know if this process is finished a ask for this XML which contains "processing", "done" or "not exist"